# How to prevent overbooking rooms?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to make restriction for new reservation between two dates. For example during Reservation I selected DateIN is 24/12/2013 and DateOUT is 28/12/2013 and selected Room No. and saved the record in database.

Now I want to restrict any reservation between these two dates like there should be restriction to Reserve room. For example DateIN= 26/12/2013 and DateOut= 30/12/2013 because room is already booked till 28/12/2013 so DateIN must be greater than 28/12/2013.

How can I make this restriction using VB.NET and MS Access? I tried this code but it fails in some conditions.

```
con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
con.Open()
Dim ct As String = "SELECT RoomNo FROM Temp_Reservation WHERE RoomNo='" _
  & cmbRoomNo.Text & "' AND DateOut BETWEEN  #" & dtpDateIN.Text _
  & "# AND  #" & dtpDateOut.Text _
  & "# AND Status='Confirmed' AND DateIN < #" & dtpDateOut.Text & "#"
cmd = New OleDbCommand(ct)
cmd.Connection = con
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
If rdr.Read Then
    MessageBox.Show("Selected Room is already booked", "Input Error", _
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    If Not rdr Is Nothing Then
        rdr.Close()
    End If
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: what do you mean it fails some time? errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the room is already booked from before the new in date until after the new out date then your BETWEEN clause will not detect them. I assume that someone can check in the same day as some else checks out. Test like this

```
Temp_Reservation.DateIn < new_out AND Temp_Reservation.DateOut > new_in
    ==> booking conflict!
```

Example:

```
 Reservation A:   26/12/2013 to 28/12/2013  
 Reservation B:   10/01/2014 to 15/01/2014  
 Reservation new: 01/01/2014 to 05/01/2014  

 A_in(26/12/2013) < new_out(05/01/2014) AND A_out(28/12/2013) > new_in(01/01/2014)
     ===> True AND False = False (which means: no conflicting record will be returned)

  B_in(10/01/2014) < new_out(05/01/2014) AND B_out(15/01/2014) > new_in(01/01/2014)
     ===> False AND True = False
```

---

How I found the logic: First I formulated the condition bookings have to fulfill in order to be OK.

```
OK:        A_in >= B_out OR A_out <= B_in
```

But you want to find overlapping bookings. Therefore I turned the condition around according to [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): `NOT (x OR y) = NOT(x) AND NOT(y)`

```
CONFLICT:  A_in < B_out AND A_out > B_in
```

Comment: but it wont allow reservation between not reserved dates....
1st Reservation 26/12/2013 to 28/12/2013
2nd Reservation 10/01/2014 to 15/01/2014
so this query will not allow third reservation
1/01/2014 to 05/01/2014..........query fails in this condition...

Comment: i cant leave not reserved dates....any advance booking even up to 6 months are allowed.......

Comment: Yes it will, because this will be tested independently for each booking record. If the room is reserved before, `DateOut` will not be greater than `new_in`. If the room is reserved after, `DateIn` will not be less than `new_out`.

Comment: More elegant (and probably faster) than mine, though less easy for a human (such as myself) to arrive at or understand...

Comment: @MontyWild: I added an explanation to my answer which makes it easier for humans to understand :-)

Comment: this query also worked for any case...i checked so many cases...
thanks sir :)

Answer (score 3):

When checking for room booking overlaps like this (where you have a set checkout/checkin time), you need to check for other bookings where:

The Current Enquiry's `DateIn` is: less than the other booking's `DateOut` and greater than or equal to the other booking's `DateIn`

*Or*

The Current Enquiry's `DateOut` is: greater than the other booking's `Datein` and less than or equal to the other booking's `DateOut`

*Or*

The Current Enquiry's `DateIn` is less than the other booking's `DateIn` and the Current Enquiry's `DateOut` is greater than the other booking's `DateOut`

i.e.:

```
Dim ct As String
ct = String.Format("Select RoomNo from Temp_Reservation where RoomNo=""{0}""" & _
                   "And Status = ""Confirmed"" And " & _
                   "(#{1}# < DateOut And #{1}# >= DateIn) " & _
                   "Or (#{2}# > DateIn  And #{2}# <= DateOut) " & _
                   "Or (#{1}# < DateIn And #{2}# > DateOut)", _
                   cmbRoomNo.Text, dtpDateIN.Text, dtpDateOut.Text)
```

Comment: While you say that my answer works, I would still suggest that Olivier Jacot-Descombes answer would serve you better.  Not that I object to the rep for the accepted answer...